# jquery UI dialog scroll follow?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

How is it possible for a jquery UI dialog to follow window scroll ?

Comment: `position: fixed`

Comment: this only works with the dialog content not the whole dialog

Comment: try this: `ui-dialog {position: fixed !important}`

Comment: did you add `.ui-dialog` or `ui-dialog`, and do you realize this is CSS?

Comment: yup, u had to mention its a class, it works now ! thanks

Comment: Using !important to enforce fixed actually messed up my closing animation. Instead I had to make the selector specific to my own class and remove !important. .ui-dialog.fixed-dialog { position: fixed; } Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible but you need to override the base jQueryUI styles, so make sure (in your CSS) you have:

```
.ui-dialog {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
  }

p {
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  }

.ui-dialog {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
  <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
</div>


<!--these are here to help show that the dialogue is actually fixed -->
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
<p>D</p>
<p>E</p>
<p>F</p>
```